# How to calculate a densitiy distribution for a set of values in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas, ipython

I have a pandas data frame and would like to calculate density distribution function for these values. Would be nice to have something like that:

```
df['col_name'].dens()
```

However, if something like that does not exist, I can put all these value to a list and then use some other functions that calculate a density distribution function for values in a list. It would be great if I can do it in either of these packages: `scipy`, `numpy`, `ipython`, `scikit`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` and just pass it the dataframe column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':np.random.randn(100)}) # 100 normally distributed values
g = sp.stats.gaussian_kde(df.a)
[g(x)[0] for x in np.linspace(-3,3,10)]
```

gives:

```
[0.010404194709511637,
 0.028412197910606129,
 0.093548960033717946,
 0.1915548075057672,
 0.29626128014747688,
 0.3402226687259407,
 0.29679380013692241,
 0.15516355334523385,
 0.057147975947743457,
 0.020153062250794138]
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a density plot: `df['col_name'].plot(kind='density')`

Comment: if I do what you suggest I get no error messages but also no result (no figure). What does the given command return?

Comment: If you're in IPython notebook with inline plotting enabled, the command will produce a density plot immediately. I'm guessing that's not the case, so you could try: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; df['col_name'].plot(kind='density'); plt.show()`